# iOS - Load xib and assign objects

Tags: ios, uiview, xib

I was wondering if anyone knew why I was getting an error when I do this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingScreen" owner:self options:NULL];
        self = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        self.spinner = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
        self.loadingLabel = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
        self.shortDescLabel = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:3];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)awakeFromNib
{

    self.loadingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:20];
    self.shortDescLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FaunaOne-Regular" size:18];
}
```

I'm getting this error:

2014-07-15 09:32:49.431 [4625:90b] -[UIView setSpinner:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d02b350

Comment: where is your set spinner method ?/

Comment: self.spinner = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:1]; in the initWithFrame method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingScreen" owner:self options:NULL];
 self = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

By doing this you are initialising self from what ever top most object you are getting from the Xib file.

> [UIView setSpinner:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d02b350

From the error it is clear you are getting `UIView` instead of `YourCustomView` while loading the xib. So probably you may not ***set the Class of the view to `YourCustomView` in the Xib file***. Check the interface for the class name of your custom view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `self` is being interpreted as a `UIView` instead of your custom view on this line:

```
self.spinner = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
```

This line is asking `UIView` for a "spinner" property, which it does not have. Thus, causing your error. You need to set your custom class in your NIB so that it is interpreted as your custom view and not a `UIView`.

[image]

Comment: That code I pasted above is inside the "YourCustomView" class file.